# What is the best fitness app for logging calorie intake, log exercise details, create weekly workout plans?

Tags: tracking

I'm looking for an android app that has below features:

- Calorie Counter(including macros)
- Log body size and weight measurements
- Create weekly/monthly workout plan day by day to ease remembering the exercises on the gym. I'm not an expert so most of the time I need to go to Youtube and check how was that exercise done.
- Track and log exercise details like repetition number, how much did I lift and how much did I struggle

I tried most of the famous fitness apps but most of them are focusing on either diet or workout. I couldn't find one to track all of them in one app.

I think these are the most common requirements for a complete fitness app. What do you think? Should I use different apps for each of them or should I keep using excel?